# How create a mandatory field in runtime using a ClientDataset

Tags: delphi

I'm using this code to create a set of  fields in runtime

```
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger, 0);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Serial', ftInteger, 0);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Customer', ftString, 40);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Address', ftString, 40);
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
```

Now I want to  make some fields mandatory, how i can define a field created in runtime as mandatory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The add method has a fourth parameter called *required*

```
procedure Add(const Name: string; DataType: TFieldType; Size: Integer = 0;
  Required: Boolean = False);
```

set that value to True and your field will be mandatory.

example to make mandatory the field `ID` use this code

```
ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger, 0, True);
```